# ZF3 - EventManager and dispatch event

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

in an older ZF2 application I change the layout in a dispatch listener, if the matched route starts with `admin`. Now I started a new project and want to use ZF3 components, but the event manager does have some changes and I get the following exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Zend\EventManager\EventManager::attach() must be callable, none given

I don't know really how to handle this in ZF3. Here are my relevant source codes to change the layout in my ZF2 application:

**Module.php**

```
namespace Admin;

use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface {

    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event) {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

        $eventManager->attach($serviceManager->get('Admin\Listener\Dispatch'));
    }

}
```

**DispatchListener.php**

```
namespace Admin\Listener;

use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class DispatchListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate {

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager) {
        $this->listeners[] = $eventManager->attach(
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'), 100
        );
    }

    public function onDispatch(EventInterface $event) {
        $matchedRouteName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();

        if (strpos($matchedRouteName, 'admin') === 0) {
            $event->getViewModel()->setTemplate('layout/admin');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add second argument to the:  public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager, $priodity = 1) {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zf3 is more focused on decoupling components, it seems aggregates has been removed to attach event see the api document

[event manager](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-eventmanager/api/)

for short the attach message says

```
attach($eventName, callable $listener, $priority = 1) : callable
```

I hope since you are not specifying the eventName you are getting the error message

update:

see the link to migration guide from v2 to v3 for event manager

[Removed functions](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-eventmanager/migration/removed/)

Comment: Aggregates still exist see the documentation: [Docs ZF - Event manager - Aggregates](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-eventmanager/aggregates/)

Comment: Alright, I changed the listener attachment in my Module.php to the following and everything works fine now. Thanks a lot! `$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,[$serviceManager->get(Listener\DispatchListener::class), 'onDispatch']);`

Answer (score 0):

In ZF3 you can change your layout for your controller this easy way:

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyModule;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    // The "init" method is called on application start-up and 
    // allows to register an event listener.
    public function init(ModuleManager $manager)
    {
        // Get event manager.
        $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        // Register the event listener method. 
        $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', 
                                    [$this, 'onDispatch'], 100);
    }

    // Event listener method.
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // Get controller to which the HTTP request was dispatched.
        $controller = $event->getTarget();
        // Get fully qualified class name of the controller.
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        // Get module name of the controller.
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

        // Switch layout only for controllers belonging to our module.
        if ($moduleNamespace == __NAMESPACE__) {
            $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/layout2');  
        }        
    }

    // ...
}
```